# Using the value of a dynamic <select> to show an <input type="text>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am building a form for my business where I use two `<select>` fields (the 2nd `<select>` relies on values in the 1st `<select>` to populate it) and two `<input type="text">` fields

The logic works like this, the user selects a location from the 1st `<select>`;

1. an "onchange" fires; and,
2. determines whether to:

   a) show the second `<select>`; or,

   b) the two input fields "Other Location" and "Other College".

   This all works swimmingly well.

I run into problems when I try to use an "onchange" event in the dynamic `<select>` to test if the user selects "Other. The code that hides the 2nd `<select>` and the two `<input>` fields, breaks and show all 3 when they should be hidden.
Here is the code for dynamic1, this code does what its supposed to do, based on the value selected in "location"

```
function dynamic1(parent,child){
//You will have to adjust the parent arrays and the values assigned to them in order to insert the values of your choice
var parent_array = new Array();
    parent_array[0] = ['Please select a location...'];
    parent_array[1] = ['Please select a university ...' ,'Macquarie University','UNSW','AICE','Sydney University','Western Sydney University','UWS','Australian Catholic University','Other'];
    parent_array[2] = ['Please select a university..','University of Newcastle','Australian Catholic University','Other'];
    parent_array[3] = ['Please select a university ...','Central Coast TAFE','Language College','Other'];
    parent_array[4] = ['Please select a university','ANU', 'University of Canberra','Australian Catholic University','Other'];
    parent_array[5] = ['Please select a university ...','Melbourne University','Monash University','Deakin University','Victoria University','Swinburne University','RMIT','Australian Catholic University','Other'];
    parent_array[6] = ['Please select a university ...','University of Queensland','QUT','Australian Catholic University','Other'];
    parent_array[7] = ['Please select a university ...','Edith Cowan','Murdoch','University of WA','WAAPA', 'Other'];
    parent_array[8] =['Please enter your city ...'];

var thechild = document.getElementById(child);
thechild.options.length = 0;
var parent_value = parent.options[parent.selectedIndex].value;
if (!parent_array[parent_value]) parent_value = '';
     thechild.options.length = parent_array[parent_value].length;
     for(var i=0;i<parent_array[parent_value].length;i++){
         thechild.options[i].text = parent_array[parent_value][i];
         thechild.options[i].value = parent_array[parent_value][i];} }

/there is code above this that populates the dynamic <select> and has the   css */  

function handleCourseLocation(){
    var e = document.getElementById('location');
    var opt = e.options[e.selectedIndex];

    var oln = document.getElementById('otherlocation');
    var uni = document.getElementById('university');
    var otuni = document.getElementById('otheruni');

    if (opt.value == 0){
        oln.style.display ="none";
        uni.style.display ="none";
        otuni.style.display ="none";
    }
    else if (opt.value==8){
        oln.style.display ="";
        uni.style.display ="none";
        otuni.style.display ="";
    }
    else {
        oln.style.display ="none";
        uni.style.display ="";
        otuni.style.display ="none";
    } 
}
/* this is the function that fails */
/*(function handleUni(){
    var f=document.getElementById('university');
    var optf = f.options[f.selectedIndex];
    var otuni = document.getElementById('otheruni');

    If (optf.text == "Other"){
        otuni.style.display="";
    }
    else {
        otuni.style.display="none";
    }
} */

function dynamicCourse(parent, child){
    dynamic1(parent, child);
    handleCourseLocation();
}   
</script>
<style>
    body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
        padding-bottom: 40px; /* 40 px to provide clearance at the bottom for a bottom fixed navbar*/
        padding-left: 10%;
        padding-right:10%
    }
    select:invalid {
        color: gray; 
    }
    option:first {
        color: gray;
    }
</style>
</head>
 <body  onload="handleCourseLocation();">
     <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Details about you</legend>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">first name &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="e.g. Wendy, Min etc"  maxlength="60" size="60"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">family name &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls"</div>
                    <input  type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="e.g. Xu, Smith etc" maxlength="60" size="60"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for ="input-label">your email &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="email@somewhere.com" size="80"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">your birthday &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="date" id="birthdate"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">gender &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="span1"id="gender"/>
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">telephone &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls controls-row">
                    <input class="span1" type="text" id="country" placeholder="61" maxlength="3"/>
                    <input class="span5" type="text" id="telnumber" placeholder="9999-9999" maxlength="10"/>
                </div>
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          <p> &nbsp;</p>
          <fieldset>
              <legend>Details about your course</legend>
              <p>We strive to make your travel time from your homestay to your institution to be less than 45 minutes. To achieve this we need to know when you start your course and where you will be studying when you are here.</p>
              <div class="control-group">
                  <label class="control-label" for="input-label">start date&nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="date" id="cseStart"/>
                </div>  
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">location &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls controls-row">
                    <select class="span2" id="location" required onchange="dynamicCourse(this,'university');"/> 
                    <option value = 0>Please select city or town ...</option>
                    <option value = 1>Sydney</option>
                    <option value = 2>Newcastle</option>
                    <option value = 3>Gosford/Central Coast</option>
                    <option value = 4>Canberra</option>
                    <option value = 5>Melbourne</option>
                    <option value = 6>Brisbane</option>
                    <option value = 7>Perth</option>
                    <option value = 8>Other city</option>
                </select>
                <input type = "text" id="otherlocation" placeholder="please type the city or town your college is in" maxlength ="60" size = "42"/>
                <select class="span3" id="university" name="university" />
                </select>
                <input type = "text" id="otheruni" placeholder="please type your university or college" maxlength ="60" size = "42" />
            </div>
          </fieldset>
          <p> &nbsp;</p>
          <fieldset>
              <legend>Details about your homestay needs ...</legend>
              <p>To help us find you a homestay family to meet your needs, we need to know a little more about what type of homestay you are looking for.</p>
          </fieldset>
      </form>
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Can you give an example what the content for `university` looks like? Does `handleUni` get called on the `onchange` event for `university`?

Comment: Why the jQuery tag, are you looking for one written in it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I made a few minor syntax changes and it seems to be working fine. Let me know if this isn't as expected.

```
<html>

<head>
    <script>
    function dynamic1(parent, child) { //You will have to adjust the parent arrays and the values assigned to them in order to insert the values of your choice 
        var parent_array = new Array();
        parent_array[0] = ['Please select a location...'];
        parent_array[1] = ['Please select a university ...', 'Macquarie University', 'UNSW', 'AICE', 'Sydney University', 'Western Sydney University', 'UWS', 'Australian Catholic University', 'Other'];
        parent_array[2] = ['Please select a university..', 'University of Newcastle', 'Australian Catholic University', 'Other'];
        parent_array[3] = ['Please select a university ...', 'Central Coast TAFE', 'Language College', 'Other'];
        parent_array[4] = ['Please select a university', 'ANU', 'University of Canberra', 'Australian Catholic University', 'Other'];
        parent_array[5] = ['Please select a university ...', 'Melbourne University', 'Monash University', 'Deakin University', 'Victoria University', 'Swinburne University', 'RMIT', 'Australian Catholic University', 'Other'];
        parent_array[6] = ['Please select a university ...', 'University of Queensland', 'QUT', 'Australian Catholic University', 'Other'];
        parent_array[7] = ['Please select a university ...', 'Edith Cowan', 'Murdoch', 'University of WA', 'WAAPA', 'Other'];
        parent_array[8] = ['Please enter your city ...'];
        var thechild = document.getElementById(child);
        thechild.options.length = 0;
        var parent_value = parent.options[parent.selectedIndex].value;
        if (!parent_array[parent_value]) parent_value = '';
        thechild.options.length = parent_array[parent_value].length;
        for (var i = 0; i < parent_array[parent_value].length; i++) {
            thechild.options[i].text = parent_array[parent_value][i];
            thechild.options[i].value = parent_array[parent_value][i];
        }
    }
    /*there is code above this that populates the dynamic <select> and has the css */
    function handleCourseLocation() {
        var e = document.getElementById('location');
        var opt = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
        var oln = document.getElementById('otherlocation');
        var uni = document.getElementById('university');
        var otuni = document.getElementById('otheruni');
        if (opt.value == 0) {
            oln.style.display = "none";
            uni.style.display = "none";
            otuni.style.display = "none";
        } else if (opt.value == 8) {
            oln.style.display = "";
            uni.style.display = "none";
            otuni.style.display = "";
        } else {
            oln.style.display = "none";
            uni.style.display = "";
            otuni.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    /* this is the function that fails */
    function handleUni() {
            var f = document.getElementById('university');
            var optf = f.options[f.selectedIndex];
            var otuni = document.getElementById('otheruni');
            if(optf.text == "Other") {
                otuni.style.display = "";
            } else {
                otuni.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        function dynamicCourse(parent, child) {
            dynamic1(parent, child);
            handleCourseLocation();
        }
    </script>
    <style>
    body {
        padding-top: 60px;
        /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        /* 40 px to provide clearance at the bottom for a bottom fixed navbar*/
        padding-left: 10%;
        padding-right: 10%
    }

    select:invalid {
        color: gray;
    }

    option:first {
        color: gray;
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body onload="handleCourseLocation();">
    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Details about you</legend>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">first name &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="e.g. Wendy, Min etc" maxlength="60" size="60" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">family name &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls" </div>
                    <input type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="e.g. Xu, Smith etc" maxlength="60" size="60" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">your email &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="email@somewhere.com" size="80" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">your birthday &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="date" id="birthdate" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">gender &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <select class="span1" id="gender" />
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">telephone &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls controls-row">
                    <input class="span1" type="text" id="country" placeholder="61" maxlength="3" />
                    <input class="span5" type="text" id="telnumber" placeholder="9999-9999" maxlength="10" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <p> &nbsp;</p>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Details about your course</legend>
            <p>We strive to make your travel time from your homestay to your institution to be less than 45 minutes. To achieve this we need to know when you start your course and where you will be studying when you are here.</p>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">start date&nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="date" id="cseStart" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="input-label">location &nbsp;</label>
                <div class="controls controls-row">
                    <select class="span2" id="location" required onchange="dynamicCourse(this,'university');" />
                    <option value=0>Please select city or town ...</option>
                    <option value=1>Sydney</option>
                    <option value=2>Newcastle</option>
                    <option value=3>Gosford/Central Coast</option>
                    <option value=4>Canberra</option>
                    <option value=5>Melbourne</option>
                    <option value=6>Brisbane</option>
                    <option value=7>Perth</option>
                    <option value=8>Other city</option>
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" id="otherlocation" placeholder="please type the city or town your college is in" maxlength="60" size="42" />
                    <select class="span3" id="university" name="university" />
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" id="otheruni" placeholder="please type your university or college" maxlength="60" size="42" />
                </div>
        </fieldset>
        <p> &nbsp;</p>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Details about your homestay needs ...</legend>
            <p>To help us find you a homestay family to meet your needs, we need to know a little more about what type of homestay you are looking for.</p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
</parent_array[parent_value].length;i++){>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: Here is the function dynamic1.